# Algorithm to assign Team based on player's choice

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I found very similar questions in here but I couldn't find a solution which would work for me. So here's the problem:

I have 4 teams and a vast (higher than 4) number of players. Each player ranks the teams by their liking, example:

1. Team B
2. Team D
3. Team A
4. Team C

In the end I want to have an even number of players in each team but weighted by their choices.

It's a Hungarian algorithm, with more men than jobs. Can anyone help me find the algorithm for this? I have been searching for a long time.

Comment: That looks more like a variation of the [Hospitals/Residents Problem](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/publications/PAPERS/5784/SWAT00.pdf) (or College Admissions Problem), maybe without any ranking on the 'hospital' side.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent this as a sort-of 1-0 integer programming problem.

Let x_N be a vector describing team assignment: person i is on team Y if x_Y(i) = 1, and if they're not on team Y then x_Y(i) = 0. |x_Y| = N, where N is the number of players.

Also, let p_Y be the player's preference weighting for team Y, so that p_Y(i) = 4 if player i really wants to be on team Y, and p_Y(i) = 1 if they don't want to be on team Y.

(You can replace the weighted preferences 1 and 4 with whatever, they're just an example).

An algorithm which solves your problem must do the following:

Maximize: x_A*p_A + x_B*p_B + x_C*p_C + x_D*p_D

Subject to: x_A + x_B + x_C + x_D = 1 (the vector with N ones)

AND x_Y(i) in {0, 1} for all Y in {A, B, C, D}, i in {1, ..., N}

What you're maximizing is actually the trace of the matrix product of assignment and preference matrices, which is a semidefinite integer programming algorithm. I'm pretty sure that's NP-hard.

One heuristic to solve this is to randomly assign an equal number of players to teams. Then, you can make a series of "trades" between teams if they make the objective function increase. Better yet, you can figure out in polynomial time which trade is the best one at any given assignment. This will not give you an optimal assignment, but I think it will get you pretty close.

This method, by the way, is a variation on [hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). Basically, any of these other [heuristic methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Heuristic_methods) will have a similar analog in the context of this problem.

Comment: I would be inclined to start the algorithm part way up the hill.  Rather than assign players randomly initially, assign each player to their most preferred choice of team with empty slots.  Then run the hill climbing algorithm from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Notations:**

*Player array*: `p[1], ..., p[n]`

*Team array*: `T[1], T[2], T[3], T[4]`

*Willingness matrix*: `w[i,j]`; dimension = `nx4`; `w[i,j]`= willingness of `pi` to be in team `Tj`. The assumption here is that `w[i,1] + w[i,2] + w[i,3] + w[i,4] = 1` for all `i`.

*Membership matrix*: `x[i,j]`, dimension = `nx4`; `x[i,j]=1` or `0` depending whether `pi` belongs in `Tj` or not.

*Satisfaction array*: `s[1], ..., s[n]`; `s[i] := w[i,1] * x[i,1] + ... + w[i,4] * x[i,4]`.

*Satisfaction*: `s := (s[1] + ... + s[n]) / n`.

**Operation:**

Assume the following:

1. `x[k,q] = 1` (`p[k]` belongs in `T[q]`)
2. `x[k,r] = 0` (`p[k]` does not belong in `T[r]`
3. `x[h,r] = 1` (`p[h]` belongs in `T[r]`)
4. `x[h,q] = 0` (`p[h]` does not belong in `T[q]`

The operation `swap([k,q][h,r])` interchanges players `p[k]` and `p[h]` between teams `T[q]` and `T[r]`. This is:

1. `x[k,q] := 0`, `x[k,r] := 1`.
2. `x[h,r] := 0`, `x[h,q] := 1`.
3. `s[k] := s[k] - w[k,q] + w[k,r]`, `s[h] = s[h] - w[h,r] + w[h,q]`.
4. `s := (s * n - w[k,q] - w[h,r] + w[h,r] + w[k,q]) / n`.

Now you are ready to use Simulated Annealing to maximize the satisfaction `s`. Here is a sketch of the algorithm:

1. Start with any configuration (just assign players to teams as they show up)
2. Establish a temperature
3. Pick two pairs `[k,q]` and `[h,r]` at random
4. Try the `swap` operation. If the satisfaction `s` increases, accept the swap. If it doesn't, accept it only with certain probability, otherwise reject the swap (see the Simulated Annealing algorithm for details)
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 a number of times.
6. Decrease the temperature and go back to 3.

**Remarks:**

If players have preferences in the range `1, ..., 4` (or any other,) divide for every player those numbers by their sum to get the willingness vector of each of them satisfy the constraint `w[i,1] + ... + w[i,4] = 1`.

The random selection of two pairs `[h,q]` and `[k,r]` must satisfy the assumptions of the `swap` operation. So, it basically consists in choosing two teams at random (`q` and `r`) and then two players one in each team.

Steps 3 and 4 in the `swap` operation are essential to minimize the number of sums and products, so swap trials are fast.

To reject a `swap`, just `swap` again the same pairs.